# The Analytics Parameter Price parameter in Firebase is adding extra numbers by itself

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase

I m sending AnalyticsEventSelectItem as a log event but problem is about AnalyticsParameterPrice parameter.For example price data comes "39,95 TL" (TL: turkish liras) but price is 39950000 in firebase console.

**My event**

```
        let value = Double(model.price.components(separatedBy: " TL").first?.replacingOccurrences(of: ",", with: ".") ?? "") ?? 0.0
    let product: [String:Any] = [
        AnalyticsParameterItemID: model.sku,
        AnalyticsParameterItemName: model.name,
        AnalyticsParameterItemCategory: "\(genderCategoryTitle) / \(genderCategoryTitle) \(sectionCategoryName) / \(categoryName)",
        AnalyticsParameterItemVariant: model.color ?? "",
        AnalyticsParameterItemBrand: "Skechers",
        AnalyticsParameterPrice: value
    ]
    
    var selectedItem: [String: Any] = [
        AnalyticsParameterItemListID: categoryID,
        AnalyticsParameterItemListName: "\(genderCategoryTitle) / \(genderCategoryTitle) \(sectionCategoryName) / \(categoryName)",
        AnalyticsParameterItemVariant: model.color ?? "",
    ]
    
    selectedItem[AnalyticsParameterItems] = [product]
    Analytics.logEvent(AnalyticsEventSelectItem, parameters: selectedItem)
```

Comment: `.replacingOccurrences(of: ",", with: ".")` is definitely a bad idea

Comment: data comes with comma from backend so what should I do

Comment: Use the right tags.  How do you go from 'Firebase' to 'The Analytics Parameter Price parameter'?

Comment: @BatuhanBaran well it depends on how you store your info. Why are you storing a number as a string?

Comment: @ElTomato I use this AnalyticsParameterPrice I can see the parameter on firebase but I see it by itself with an extra zero added.

Comment: @LeoDabus when model.price comes as "314,50 TL", I use components and replacingOccurrences functions and my value variable converting 314.50 successfully.Also I can print it in log but when I put it my parameters dictionary and send event,I see 314.50000 like this on firebase.

Comment: @BatuhanBaran the point is who is feeding this data?

Comment: Firebase has several different services.  If you are referring to Firebase Analytics, use that one instead of the firebase tag, unless you are talking about their server software.

Comment: @BatuhanBaran did you solve your issue? I'm seeing the same: my item_price Double(29.5) shows up as 29500000 in Firebase's debug view.